# Which crew skills complement each other?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I was wondering, which of the [crew skills](http://www.swtor.com/info/systems/crew-skills) are complementary? Like mining and smelting in WoW, which gets the components for which?

Comment: Slicing isn't complimentary directly, but is a general 'make money'  skill; "money can be exchanged for goods and services" -Homer. You can buy mats on the GTN. So Slicing is indirectly complimentary to all crafting skills.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a very handy diagram for how the crew skills relate to each other.

[image: crew skills diagram]

Comment: Looks like a lot of the crossing lines could be solved by rearranging some icons. E.g. swapping Archaeology and Treasure Hunting.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a graph that delineates gathering, crafting, and missions.

[image]

—from [SWTOR Crew Skills Diagram](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1ZRKcqEYQh6jigt902hkC-0Pj-83OAA15Br0d4pGidPY/edit?pli=1) on Google Docs

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Please edit your post to show the relevant parts here so that if the link dies, your answer will still be helpful.  Also, see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-could-i-write-my-answer-that-links-to-an-external-resource-properly) that explains how to properly write answers that links to external sites. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This site contains a useful list of the most efficient Crew Skill combinations for each class based on the companion skill bonuses: http://r2-db.com/guide/124/skill-choices-based-on-companion-bonuses

CREW SKILLS

The following is a list of all the crew skills and their related Mission and Gathering counterparts:

```
Armormech - Scavenging - Underworld Trading
Armstech - Scavenging - Investigation
Artifice - Archaeology - Treasure Hunting
Biochem - Bioanalysis - Diplomacy
Cybertech - Scavenging - Underworld Trading
Synthweaving - Archaeology - Underworld Trading
Slicing - This Gathering skill is not associated with any Crafting skill
```

- Armormech and Armstech are speficially for non-Force users.
- Artifice and Synthweaving are specifically for Force users.
- Biochem and Cybertech can be useful to all players regardless of their use of the Force.

---

SITH INQUISITOR

- Artifice - Archaeology - Treasure Hunting
- Synthweaving - Archaeology - Underworld Trading

SITH WARRIOR

- Cybertech - Scavenging - Underworld Trading Synthweaving
- Archaeology - Underworld Trading

BOUNTY HUNTER

- Armormech - Underworld Trading - Scavenging
- Cybertech - Underworld Trading - Scavenging

IMPERIAL AGENT

- Armstech - Scavenging - Investigation
- Biochem - Bioanalysis - Diplomacy

JEDI CONSULAR

- Synthweaving - Archaeology - Underworld Trading
- Cybertech - Scavenging - Underworld Trading

JEDI KNIGHT

- Synthweaving - Archaeology - Underworld Trading
- Artifice - Archaeology - Treasure Hunting

SMUGGLER

- Armormech - Underworld Trading - Scavenging
- Cybertech - Underworld Trading - Scavenging

TROOPER

- Armormech - Underworld Trading - Scavenging
- Armstech - Investigation - Scavenging
- Biochem - Bioanalysis - Diplomacy