# Which crew skills are appropriate for each class?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

What crafting skills (and in turn [their related skills](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42375/which-crew-skills-complement-each-other)) are good for each class?

I was thinking about doing Biochem on my Jedi Shadow as it seemed fairly general (a la *WoW* Alchemist) and I already have synthweaving on my Sith Sorcerer.  My other characters are also approaching time to leave their starting planets as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In general, Force Users will want to look at *Artifice* and *Synthweaving*, Non-Force Users will want to look at *Armormech* and *Armstech*. *Cybertech* and *Biochem* are of interest to all classes.**

For Gathering and Mission skills, simply [choose the ones that best compliment your choice of crafting skill](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42375/which-crew-skills-complement-each-other), or, if so inclined [those you feel will be most profitable.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44013/how-can-i-earn-lots-of-credits)

Some things to note about the specific value of each skill:

**Biochem** is likely the most useful at endgame, as it's the only skill that is capable of providing an item that fills a recurring player need (Stims/Medpacks), and which is not purely replaceable with drops. Of particular note are the *reusable* Stims and Medpacks which Biochemists can make for themselves. As far as equipment goes, Biochem also provides recipes for **Implants**, so you can reliably fill and upgrade two equipment slots for yourself and any companions as you level. *Biochem is a great choice for players that prefer to rely heavily on consumables, and don't mind relying on drops and vendors for gear.*

**Cybertech** is the best choice if you are intent on using [orange items to maintain a specific 'look' for your character and or your companions.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44156/whats-the-deal-with-orange-items-without-stats) Cybertech provides the **Armoring** and **Mod** slots for these items - two of the 4 slots found on most Weapons and Armor. In addition, Cybertechs can fully outfit Droid companions, as well as producing **Earpieces** for themselves and companions (filling one equipment slot with up to date gear at all times), and **Ship Upgrades**. Finally, Cybertechnicians get to make their own cool custom speeder bikes. *Cybertech is a great choice for players who prefer 'custom' (Orange) armor, classes that rely on droid companions (Trooper, Jedi Knight, and Imperial Agent, or anyone who is fond of the Ship Droid), and those who are very fond of space combat missions.*

**Artifice** is primarily aimed at Force Users, but others *can* make use of this tradeskills ability to create **Color Crystals** and **Enhancements**. The former are used in Blasters as well as Light Sabers, and most orange equipment has slots for the latter. While a Lightsaber user will benefit more, it's not a horrific choice for others. One notable limitation is that very few companions use Lightsabers, so Artifice isn't the best choice for outfitting them.

**Synthweaving** is almost exclusively useful to Force Users. It provides no notable crafting recipes of interest to folks who prefer Blasters to Lightsabers - and since non-force users don't have any 'Jedi' companions availiable to them, it's not even useful for equipping companions. However, for Sith or Jedi characters, *Synthweaving is a powerful choice, as it will ensure that you always have up to date gear availaible for yourself, and at least some of your companions.*

**Armstech** fills a similar role to Artifice for Blaster types. Unlike Artifice however, it provides little that would be of interest to a Force User beyond companion gear. Also unlike Artifice however, it is *much more useful* for equipping companions, since most of them do use Blasters, Vibroswords/knives, Scatterguns, and other weapons of the sort that Armstechnicians can craft.

**Armormech** is similar to Synthweaving for the pew pew set, but again, like Armstech, is much more useful in equipping companions. Like Armstech, it provides little to nothing of interest to a force user, who should skip it for Synth.

Comment: Also checkout the lv10 guides on the site for recommendations. http://www.swtor.com/progressionGuides/JediKnight10/

Answer (score -2):

I don't really have an answer, per se, but want to point out that each companion has certain skill bonuses.  If you're only going to have one or two characters, I wouldn't give a lot of thought to that, and just follow Less' recommendations.  But if you don't mind leveling a group of other characters to the point of getting certain companions, you may want to consider those skill bonuses and choose a character to do the skills you want based on that.  It isn't like you need to have your main character do all the crafting - although it helps.  The crafting character can mail the items to whichever other characters need them.